# Checking If Specific JSON Key at a Specific Dynamic Location is Null (error)

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, api

I am receiving a JSON object back from a server and am looping through the object to gather certain information. I first need to check if a certain key exists in the object at a specific location. I'm doing this as follows:

```
if (dataJSONobj.responseText['ops:world-patent-data']['ops:equivalents-inquiry']['ops:inquiry-result'][i]['exchange-documents']['exchange-document']['bibliographic-data']['references-cited']['citation'][j]['nplcit'])
//the key is in there
```

However, I am getting this error every time:

```
CaseSelector.js:322 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nplcit' of undefined*** when there is not a "nplcit" key.
```

What am I doing wrong with my syntax? I've even tried the reverse by asking if that key is not equal to `null`.

Comment: Could you post the json object?

Comment: @bhspencer - [j] was being wonky. Weston answered correctly below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`['citation'][j]` does not exist, which if this is only happening when you know that there is no `nplcit` key, there is probably some correlation between the two. But regardless of if `nplcit` exists or it doesn't, `['citation'][j]` does not.

Comment: By golly, you're right!! I've been hitting my head against a wall thinking my syntax was off.